# Textbox text change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having two Textboxes and when ever I enter the value in the Textbox one I need to get text in to Textbox two based on the validation of the Texbox one.

If I enter value 1 in Textbox one it has to check the databse and get the corresponding value for that particular value 1.

If I enter UseerId I need to get the corresponding UserName from the database on text changed of the Textbox one.

Thanks in advance...

I am using ASP.net and the simple logic is when ever I enter the userid ineed to get username in another textbox ehern the focus is lost from the first textbox from the databse..

Comment: Please post any code that you have written so far.

Comment: Ok I'm totally lost...which language are yo using? Can you paste your code?

Comment: It would be a good idea to fix those misspelled words too:)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Code:
asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtUserID_TextChanged">/asp:TextBox>

asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server">/asp:TextBox>

Code Behind:
Protected Sub txtUserID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

   txtUserName.Text = GetUserNameFromDB(txtUserID.Text)

End Sub

You can wrap the ASP.Net code in an  for a more responsive ui.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                     OnTextChanged="UserID_Changed" />
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

C# Codebehind:

```
protected void UserId_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID.Text))
   {return;}

   ///Fetch User Name from Database

   UserName.Text=....;
}
```

But please seriously give consideration to using ajax instead of full-page postbacks. Read articles on [Dave's](http://www.encosia.com) site about using jQuery with page methods.